# Get class reference from method decorator

Tags: typescript

I want to support following syntax

```
@Controller('/user')
class UserController {
  @Action('/')
  get() {

  }

}
```

now in decorators defination

```js
function Controller (options) {
 return  function(target: any) {
   let id = uuid();
   target.__id = id;
   pushInASet(id, target)
 }

}

function Action (options) {
  return function (target: any, propertyKey: string) {
    //here i want to get target.__id of its class
  }
}
```

How can i get the id which i am setting in controller ?

Answer (score 0):

So As typeScript calls method decorators first and then class decorators, i was able to achieve it by following code:

```js
  export function Controller(options: PathType | ControllerOptions): ClassDecorator {
    const {...controllerOptions} = mapOptions(options);
      return  function(constructor: Function) {
        const actions = [];

        Object.entries(constructor.prototype["methods"]).forEach(([_key, methodConfig]) => {
          console.info('_key', _key)
          console.info('methodConfig', methodConfig);
          actions.push(methodConfig);
        })
        controllerRegistery.add({
          controllerOptions,
          actions
        })
      }
  }


export class Methods {
    static GET(options) {
        return function( target: any,
          propertyKey: string | symbol,
          descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
            (target["methods"] = target["methods"] || {})[propertyKey] = {
              options,
              methodName: propertyKey,
              method: descriptor.value,
            };
            return descriptor;
        }
    }
}
```